# Performance Decrease When Using Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Sanic + Gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, sanic

I'm just starting to learn Sanic framework because of its fast benchmark. I made a simple hello world API, then connected it with Gunicorn. The performance was quite good, but when I combined it with Nginx, it became really bad. I've found out that Gunicorn processes with Nginx were limited to 1% - 4% CPU resource for each process. Without Nginx, Gunicorn could reach up to 10% for each process. I thought it was because of wrong Nginx configuration. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

**Server information:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04    
Python version: 3.7.2    
Sanic version: 18.12.0    
Processor: i3-4130
```

**Sanic + Gunicorn performance:**

```
wrk -t8 -c1000 -d60s --timeout 2s http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Running 1m test @ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  8 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    29.54ms   15.13ms 175.77ms   71.23%
    Req/Sec     4.32k     1.29k   19.46k    64.77%
  2060010 requests in 1.00m, 249.50MB read
Requests/sec:  34281.64
Transfer/sec:      4.15MB
```

**Sanic + Gunicorn + Nginx performance:**

```
wrk -t8 -c1000 -d60s --timeout 2s http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Running 1m test @ http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  8 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   364.78ms  271.20ms   1.39s    67.53%
    Req/Sec   370.88    251.66     3.52k    87.12%
  177223 requests in 1.00m, 30.42MB read
Requests/sec:   2948.79
Transfer/sec:    518.25KB
```

**Sanic app:**

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json


app = Sanic()
app.config.ACCESS_LOG = False

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return json({"hello": "world"})
```

**Gunicorn command:**

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 --workers 8 --threads 4 app:app --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker --name SanicHelloWorld
```

**Global Nginx configuration:**

```
worker_processes 8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 400000;
thread_pool sanic_thread_pool threads=32 max_queue=65536;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 25000;
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    access_log off;
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    upstream sanic-test {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

**Nginx configuration for Sanic + Gunicorn:**

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    listen [::]:8081;

    server_name sanic-test.com www.sanic-test.com;

    location / {
        aio threads=sanic_thread_pool;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are like hundreds articles on how to tune nginx for better performance, what have you researched and tried so far? What is your results?

Comment: @Fian I have tried to increase the timeout, adjust the number of workers, maximum connections, even enabled thread pools. All of them did only make little changes. When I watched Ubuntu's task manager, it showed that Gunicorn processes had really low CPU usage percentage under Nginx.

Comment: [Nginx may be buffering requests/responses to files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html), and file IO is slow. Check if this happens in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because http://nginx.org/r/proxy_buffering is set to `on` by default, e.g., when you're using http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass.

Normally, nginx is supposed to control the *backpressure* for your backend, hence, buffering makes perfect sense, as you don't want your real backend to be subject to the *Slowloris* attack vector.  Likewise, you should be doing caching and limiting the number of connections to the real backend that's behind nginx, hence, your test where you set everything to the max, yet fail to disable the buffering, is simply an unrealistic condition in real-world scenarios, hence, you're getting the very poor numbers in metrics.

If you simply want to see how much the performance is affected by simply adding another layer to your HTTP stack, you should set `proxy_buffering off;` when using `proxy_pass`.  Otherwise, the tests should be more realistic: your real backend isn't supposed to be capable of processing more requests per second than the IO parameters of the storage device as specified by http://nginx.org/r/proxy_temp_path.

Comment: I want to understand nginx side of the problem - 
If you set `proxy_buffering off`, you lose lot of nginx functionality. 
If we want to have `proxy_buffering on`, what nginx setting we should tweak? (let suppose we have world fastest nvme or ram disk for temp path)
(note, I don't see any IO parameters in proxy_temp_path. I can see some in proxy_temp_file_write_size, but can not understand them)